# Windows 7 Hard Freezes When Exiting Certain Programs (I'm baffled!)

Tags: freeze

(I have posted this elsewhere but still no fixes thus please excuse the cross-post)

Since about two weeks ago, Windows 7 (64 Bit Pro) has frozen on me quite frequently when I exit out of certain programs. Some of the programs that have caused this: Avidemux, VLC, Dreamweaver (when closing many windows at the same time), the Command Prompt (only has happened once so far but yikes!), and more. There have been no major software changes on the computer in this time aside from updating my DisplayLink drivers soon after the problem began (I thought this may have been an issue as I noticed other threads on the net about people having similar issues when exiting video-intensive computer games) and regular Windows Updates.

There are no errors posted in the event log after this happens. Hardware has not been updated recently though I did upgrade RAM about half a year ago. Windows Memory Diagnostics reported no issues.

Any idea what is causing Windows to lock? It's a total freeze, mind you. No errors and no BSOD; close a program such as any one listed above and instantly the OS is frozen. I first thought it may have been an RAM issue but since no errors are returned and closing other 'big' programs such as Opera which was using 1GB did not result in a freeze...yet.

The programs that have caused hard freezing so far have been pretty random.  Many but not all are video-related (VirtualDub, Aegisub, Avidemux) but some like the Command Prompt are anything but.  Some use a decent amount of RAM like Aegisub but most do not.  Some are CPU intensive when encoding but all the times I've closed programs, no encoding was going on and then programs like Dreamweaver don't tax the CPU at all yet hard freezing occur quite often when they are closed.

I am not noticing any performance issues with regular computing.  Programs open and work as fast as normal and video encoding has not been impaired.

Essentially, it's smooth sailing till you want to exit out of something.

I also thought this may be an overheating issue since it's summer but neither the CPU/Harddisk/Mobo rise above 55'ish Celsius even when under load.

SeaTools also reports no errors on the disk.
SFC /scannow with no issues found.
CHKDSK /r found no issues
Hard Drive has very low fragmentation (less than 1%).

Edit: I just want to clarify that Windows doesn't freeze each and every time I close one of the above-mentioned programs. I'd say it's 70/30 in favor of freezing. Sometimes I get 'lucky'.

This freezing issue is incredible baffling as unlike your average hard freeze, the results are pretty much reproducible.  Closing certain programs will almost certain lead to Windows locking up with no BSOD.

Thanks.

Edit:  As requested, computer involved is a Thinkpad T500 laptop.

Comment: Where else did you post this?

Comment: Take a look at the eventlog (win+r, then type "eventvwr.msc" and enter)

Comment: Shlck:  I posted it on Microsoft Answers and Reddit /r/techsupport

Comment: Vandis:  No errors shown regarding the freezes.  That's what makes this so hard to pin down.  No BSOD, no event errors, nothing.  Just a hard freeze.

Comment: Psycogeek>>Thanks for the reply.  I forgot to mention that the laptop is already external cooled with a laptop cooler.  It also has a regular human fan blowing on it at all times.  Also, if it was is a ram issue, how come larger pieces of software like Opera which uses 1+GB of ram seem to close without freezing windows?

Comment: Edit:  It doesn't seem editing ram timings on a Thinkpad T500 stock bios is possible.

Comment: sorry my tests were desktop based, I re-read your post even to see if it was a laptop  :-(  Please add that info to question. I am Deleting the comment, as it has almost zero value here.  Trade it up with. It MAY be a hardware issue, dust it out refresh thermal pastes and test with less ram sticks.  Test first with some different OS like one of the linux things that runs off of CD or flash card, and see if does the same thing.

Comment: Update:  This morning I removed both sticks of ram, cleaned the slots, and put them back in with their positions swapped yet the problem still remains.  I'm actually starting to think that no program is immune to freezing the computer when closing and the only reason large ones like Opera haven't frozen the laptop yet is most likely due to luck than anything else (however again to clarify:  the freezing doesn't occur every single time a program is closed but rather most of the time).  If anyone has any more ideas, please let me know.

Comment: There is most likely no event log errors because as far as the OS is concerned, no errors have occured. It is just taking a long time to do whatever it is trying to do, it could very well be a hardware issue, my guess would be either the mobo or the CPU, or It could be a driver issue. Have you tried running the machine in safe mode? Do you notice any hard freezes?

Comment: Jason>>I actually have not tried running it in safe mode yet.  In regards to drivers, do you think running driver verifier for 24 hours such as posted on the Seven Forums would be a viable idea?  (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/101379-driver-verifier-enable-disable.html)